# Linking axis in interactive plot for holoviews layout

Tags: holoviews

I am trying to annotate some time series data with different occurrences in time. To do this I have created an overlay of curves and a holoviews.element.raster.Image (see code below).

As per [here](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/3678) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980935/how-to-link-the-axis-in-multiple-holoviews-plots) I know that the axis should have the same units and label for holoviews to automatically link them. I have tried this in the example code below, but the plots are still not linked.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# creaty dummy data
t = np.linspace(-10,10,50)
dates = pd.to_datetime(np.linspace(pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01').value, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01').value, 200))
data = np.random.rand(50,200)
xrData = xr.DataArray(data, dims=['time','dates'], coords={'time':t, 'dates':dates})

dataplot = xrData.hvplot(width=1000)
# create annotations
line1 = hv.Curve([
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-03-01'), 0],
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-06-01'), 0]], ('x','dates'), label='eventA').opts(line_width=20, color='red')

line2 = hv.Curve([
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-08-01'), 0],
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-10-01'), 0]], ('x','dates'), label='eventA').opts(line_width=20, color='red')

line3 = hv.Curve([
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-11-01'), 0],
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-12-01'), 0]], ('x','dates'), label='eventB').opts(line_width=20, color='blue')

annotations = line1 * line2 * line3

annotations.opts(width=1000,height=150, legend_cols=2, yaxis=None)
annotations = annotations.redim(y=hv.Dimension('y', range=(-0.25, 1)))


annotated_data = (annotations + dataplot).cols(1)

annotated_data
```

[Here is the plot I get in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACfXE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! Here you are wondering why the `x` axes aren't linked between these two plots, even though both are labeled "dates" and thus *seem* to be the same dimension. But if you inspect the actual dimensions of your plots, you'll see that they are different; one is "x" (but relabeled "dates" for display) and the other is "dates":

[image: dimensions]

To make them the same, you need not just to make them be *labeled* the same, but to be declared to *be* the same dimension, e.g.:

[image: new dimensions]

(How you label the dimensions onscreen is up to you; HoloViews only cares whether you actually denoted the dimensions as being the same.)

Here's your code updated with the right imports and simplified y re-ranging along with declaring the dimensions to be shared:

```py
import xarray as xr, pandas as pd, numpy as np, holoviews as hv, hvplot.xarray

# creaty dummy data
t = np.linspace(-10,10,50)
dates = pd.to_datetime(np.linspace(pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01').value, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01').value, 200))
data = np.random.rand(50,200)
xrData = xr.DataArray(data, dims=['time','dates'], coords={'time':t, 'dates':dates})

dataplot = xrData.hvplot(width=1000)
# create annotations
line1 = hv.Curve([
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-03-01'), 0],
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-06-01'), 0]], 'dates', label='eventA').opts(line_width=20, color='red')

line2 = hv.Curve([
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-08-01'), 0],
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-10-01'), 0]], 'dates', label='eventA').opts(line_width=20, color='red')

line3 = hv.Curve([
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-11-01'), 0],
    [pd.Timestamp('2017-12-01'), 0]], 'dates', label='eventB').opts(line_width=20, color='blue')

annotations = line1 * line2 * line3

annotations.opts(width=1000,height=150, legend_cols=2, yaxis=None)
annotations = annotations.redim.range(y=(-0.25, 1))


annotated_data = (annotations + dataplot).cols(1)

annotated_data
```

[image: fixed example]